# How do I put the contents of a variable to the clipboard using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

```
function Copy() // this function will be latched to a button later on.
{
    var text = writePreview(); // this pours in the formatted string by the writePreview() function to the variable 'text'
    text = br2nl(text); //variable 'text' is purified from <br/> and is replaced by a carriage return

    //I need some code here to pour in the contents of the variable 'text' to the clipboard. That way the user could paste the processed data to a 3rd party application
}
```

I'm building an offline client-side web application. The main purpose of this is to have user's input to fields, format the text such that it fits a certain criteria, then click copy so they can paste it to a 3rd party CRM.

The only available browser for this is Google Chrome. I've scoured the internet hoping to find a simple solution for this.

I'm not concerned about security as this application is not going to be published and is meant just for offline use.

I want to keep it as simple as possible and adding invisible textarea ruin the layout. Flash is not allowed in my current environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was solved by updating my browser (Google Chrome v49). I was using a lower version (v34).

found that later versions (v42+) of Google Chrome supports `document.execCommand('copy')`

I hope it helps people

here are the functions I used:

```
function SelectAll(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
    document.getElementById(id).select();
}

function copy()
{
    SelectAll('textAreaID');
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at clipboard.js

> A modern approach to copy text to clipboard
>
> No Flash. No dependencies. Just 2kb gzipped

https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: I've read about that and I got lost when it said: 

"Now, you need to instantiate it by passing a DOM selector, HTML element, or list of HTML elements."

I don't really know how to apply that to my code. If you could shed some light on that or provide a simple example, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Be concise about where you got lost. I'm agreeing with the comment of seahorsepip.

Comment: 1. I am not copying from an element
2. I am not cutting content from  an element
3. it doesn't express how to send data-clipboard-text to a variable.

While I admit , I'm not as expert as you might sound, this is the reason why I am asking the question because I've read quite a few things already and have not understood how to apply it to my current project.

I've made this work before in IE in the past however since I only have Google Chrome to work with right now, this is the reason I'm asking the question.

Comment: also, could you define what essential basic knowledge I missed so that at least I could work on it?

Answer (score 1):

According to  [this article](https://www.sharmaprakash.com.np/javascript/copying-value-from-variable-to-clipboard/)  "In javascript, copying a value from variable to clipboard is not straightforward as there is no direct command.".

Hence as suggested there I did the following:

- defined the following in html file - I added at the bottom ( I never noticed element being added and being removed ):

  `<div id="container"/>`
- then in Javascript I added:

.

```
function copyQ() {

        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var inp = document.createElement("input");
        inp.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(inp); 
        inp.value = "TEST_XYZ";
        inp.select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        alert("Copied the text: " + inp.value);
    }
```

May be there is a better way, but it works for me.

UPDATE:

Further, I found that if your text is multiline and if you use input of type text all text is converted to one line text.

To keep paragraphs / separate lines I tried to use textarea and text is copied as is - multi line:

```
    var inp = document.createElement("textarea");
    //inp.type = "text";
```

Hope it helps someone.